# Change text styles expandable list Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building a flutter app and I'm using the example code for ExpansionTile:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpansionTileSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
              new EntryItem(data[index]),
          itemCount: data.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// One entry in the multilevel list displayed by this app.
class Entry {
  Entry(this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);

  final String title;
  final List<Entry> children;
}

// The entire multilevel list displayed by this app.
final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  new Entry(
    'Chapter A',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry(
        'Section A0',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('Items:\n\nItem A0.1\nItem A0.1.1'),
          new Entry('Item A0.2'),
          new Entry('Item A0.3'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Section A1'),
      new Entry('Section A2'),
    ],
  ),

];

// Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
// with an ExpansionTile.
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);

  final Entry entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) return new ListTile(
       title: new Text(root.title));
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample/

I'm looking for a way to add bold and change the text colors of the entries, e.g., change the text: `'Items:\n\nItem A0.1\nItem A0.1.1'` to `Items:` in bold `Item A0.1` in red and `Item A0.1.1` in green.

I triend with TextSpan class but I couldn't make it work inside `Entry` class.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are looking for it's TextStyle widget the one is use inside the Text widget like this:

`Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) return new ListTile(
       title: new Text(root.title, style: TextStye(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }`

You can use that TextStyle widget to make change in color and style and weight check it out [Here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)

Or if you want to make some changes when you expand it need to make it in the onExpantionChange inside the ExpantionTile options and inside dice don't forget do it inside a setState

Comment: This is not exactly was I was looking for. Finally I left the color and style as it was. I wanted to bold some words and color others within the same entry. I'm not sure if this is really possible, but thanks anyway, and welcome to stackoverfow!

Comment: Thanks this was my first post i think that you are looking for is this.. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html hope it help! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) Widget with [css_text](https://pub.dev/packages/css_text) package.

```
String htmlContent =
"<p><b>Items</b> <span style="color:#ffff0000">Item A0.1</span>
<span style="color:#ff00ff00">Item A0.1.1</span></p>";

var myRichText = RichText(text: HTML.toTextSpan(context, htmlContent));
```

Answering after an year. It may help you or others.